# Performance of List.permute

Tags: data-structures, f#

I implemented a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) recently, which used List.permute to shuffle the list, and noted that as the size of the list increased, there was a significant performance decrease. I suspect this is due to the fact that while the algorithm assumes it is operating on an array, permute must be accessing the list elements by index, which is O(n).

To confirm this, I tried out applying a permutation to a list to reverse its element, comparing working directly on the list, and transforming the list into an array and back to a list:

```
let permute i max = max - i - 1
let test = [ 0 .. 10000 ]

let rev1 list =
   let perm i = permute i (List.length list)
   List.permute perm list

let rev2 list =
   let array = List.toArray list
   let perm i = permute i (Array.length array)
   Array.permute perm array |> Array.toList
```

I get the following results, which tend to confirm my assumption:

```
rev1 test;;
Real: 00:00:00.283, CPU: 00:00:00.265, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
rev2 test;;
Real: 00:00:00.003, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

My question is the following:

1) Should List.permute be avoided for performance reasons? And, relatedly, shouldn't the implementation of List.permute automatically do the transformation into an Array behind the scenes?

2) Besides using an Array, is there a more functional way / data structure suitable for this type of work, i.e. shuffling of elements? Or is this simply a problem for which an Array is the right data structure to use?

Comment: Good question and excellent answer. Sometimes learn a lot on S O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List.permute` [converts the list to an array, calls `Array.permute`, then converts it back to a list](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L404). Based on that, you can probably figure out what you need to do (hint: work with arrays!).

Comment: Then I don't understand why the example above doesn't give the same performance - I would expect the 2nd example to run as fast, or potentially slower because there is an extra Array conversion happening.

Comment: The reason for the difference is your use of `List.length` O(N) vs `Array.length` O(1).

Comment: You are correct! I changed rev1 to let l = (List.toArray list).Length
and let perm i = permute i l and it now runs faster. Thank you for the enlightening answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Should List.permute be avoided for performance reasons?

The only performance problem here is in your own code, specifically calling `List.length`.

> Besides using an Array, is there a more functional way / data structure suitable for this type of work, i.e. shuffling of elements? Or is this simply a problem for which an Array is the right data structure to use?

You are assuming that arrays cannot be used functionally when, in fact, they can by not mutating their elements. Consider the `permute` function:

```
let permute f (xs: _ []) = Array.init xs.Length (fun i -> xs.[f i])
```

Although it acts upon an array and produces an array it is not mutating anything so it is using an array as a purely functional data structure.