# F# Card Shuffle function

Tags: arraylist, random, f#, shuffle

I've been trying to create a simple card game in F#, i have created a simple randomizer function using system.Random.

```
type card = int
type deck = card list
let rand : int -> int = let rnd = System.Random ()
                        in fun n -> rnd.Next (0 , n )
```

However my problem is that i don't know how to create a shuffle function deck -> deck,using the rand function.

Any help is wanted.

Comment: You can use a Fisher-Yates shuffle.  See: [Can this random number generator logic be simplified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861277/3744182), [Performance of List.permute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10251744/3744182) [How to Generate A Specific Number of Random Indices for Array Element Removal F#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457044/3744182) and http://www.fssnip.net/L/title/Array-shuffle.

Comment: Also, if you construct a new `Random` every time, subsequent `Random` objects may generate identical results.  See: [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/3744182) and [Is C# Random Number Generator thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3049467/3744182).  You will need to translate those answers to f#.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort based on a random value:

```
let shuffle (d:deck) =
    let rnd = System.Random ()
    d |> List.sortBy(fun _ -> rnd.Next(1, 52) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the [solution proposed by AMieres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594805/811059) must not be used if the shuffled deck should be uniformly distributed. See this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sorting).

"A variant of the above method that has seen some use in languages that support sorting with user-specified comparison functions is to shuffle a list by sorting it with a comparison function that returns random values. However, this is an extremely bad method: it is very likely to produce highly non-uniform distributions, which in addition depends heavily on the sorting algorithm used."

As an alternative, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861277/811059).